# Looking for an efficient way of keeping menu tab up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here's what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("/db1-1") > -1) {
        $('.db1sub').closest("db1sub").css("display","block");}
    else {
        $('.db1sub').closest(".db1sub").css("display","none");}
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("/db1-2") > -1) {
        $('.db2sub').closest("db2sub").css("display","block");}
    else {
        $('.db2sub').closest(".db2sub").css("display","none");}
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("/db1-3") > -1) {
        $('.db3sub').closest("db3sub").css("display","block");}
    else {
        $('.db3sub').closest(".db3sub").css("display","none");}
});
```

And here's the section of where the code applies

```
<!--        First dashboard selection            -->
                    <li><a class="selected1" href="#">Dashboard 1</a></li>
                    <div class="db1sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard a0</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard a1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard a2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
<!--        Second dashboard selection            -->
                    <li><a class="selected2" href="#">Dashboard 2</a></li>
                    <div class="db2sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard b0</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard b1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard b2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
<!--        Third dashboard selection            -->
                    <li><a class="selected3" href="#">Dashboard 3</a></li>
                    <div class="db3sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard c0</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard c1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard c2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever one of the < li >'s in one of the lists are clicked on, that tab will stay open whenever it goes to the next page. The functionality of this right now is great and works as I want it to. However, the javascript for this seems like it can be optimized, as the if statement for db2sub and db3sub were just copy and pasted once I made the if statement for db1sub. Is there a way I can size down the code of my javascript so that I don't have to just keep copying and pasting everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var obj = { 
     "db1sub" : "/db1-1", 
     "db2sub" : "/db1-2", 
     "db3sub" : "/db1-3" 
   };
   var selectedKey = "";
   for ( var key in obj )
   {
      $('.' + key ).closest( '.' + key ).css("display","none");
      if ( window.location.href.indexOf( obj[ key ] ) > -1) 
      {
         selectedKey = key;
      }
   }
   if ( selectedKey.length > 1 ) 
   {
        $( '.' + selectedKey ).closest( '.' + selectedKey ).css("display","block");
   }
});
```

Comment: Nice! This is perfect. Thanks so much.